# XML/XSL Help <xsl:for-each>

Tags: xslt, xpath

I am trying to use  to loop through my  element, but it keeps repeating the first  element, instead of going through all of them.

Here is a snippet of my xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<customer ref="Hannah">

<fullname>

    <firstname>Hannah</firstname>

    <lastname>Hannah</lastname>

</fullname>

<meter ref="Hannah">

 <reading>

    <meterread>622224492</meterread>

</reading>

    </meter>

</customer>

<customer ref="Hannah">

<fullname>

    <firstname>Hannah</firstname>

    <lastname>Hannah</lastname>

</fullname>

<meter ref="Hannah">

<reading>

    <meterread>2822222132</meterread>

</reading>

</meter>

</customer>
```

Here is a snippet of my XSL code:

```
<xsl:for-each select="customer">
<p>Name: <xsl:value-of select="customer/fullname"/></p>

<p>Num: <xsl:value-of select="customer//@ref"/></p>

</xsl:for-each>
```

Basically, it keeps repeating the first customer, instead of looping through each  element.

Any help or suggestions would be great!

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `xsl:for-each` is selecting `customer` elements, and so inside the `xsl:for-each` you will be positioned on a `customer` element. This means your XPath expressions within the `xsl:value-of` statements need to be relative to that, rather than absolute paths.

For example, to get the full name just do this, to get the `fullname` element relative to the current `customer` element

```
<xsl:value-of select="fullname"/>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This worked. I am trying to apply this same concept/take on the other part of the document as I was having another issue similar to this. However, it is not applying :(

Answer (score 0):

Only change following code:-

```
<p>Name: <xsl:value-of select="$customerInfo//customer/fullname"/></p>
                       to
<p>Name: <xsl:value-of select="fullname"/></p>

                       and

<p>Account Number: <xsl:value-of select="$customerInfo/customer//@number"/></p>
                       to
<p>Account Number: <xsl:value-of select="@number"/></p>
```